# «Эзбекие» Гумилёва: реальность или вымысел?

Tags: литература, поэзия

Не может ли кто-нибудь рассказать: сюжет произведения «Эзбекие» полностью на вымышленной основе или он хотя бы частичное отношение имеет к реальной жизни Гумилёва?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Реально то, что он был в Эзбекие (Узбекие) — огромный сад в Исмаилии (европейской части Каира).   В 1908 году Гумилев впервые увидел Каир — и район Аль-Эзбекия, о котором он будет вспоминать потом с тоской («Как странно — ровно десять лет прошло / С тех пор, как я увидел Эзбекие...»). Он искупался в Ниле, ночевал в трюме парохода с пилигримами, был арестован за поездку «зайцем» — в общем, наслаждался жизнью. http://shakko-kitsune.livejournal.com/871400.html

Реальны отношения с Ахматовой, которая его измучила:http://do.gendocs.ru/docs/index-32146.html

Анна Ахматова познакомилась с Николаем Гумилёвым ещё подростком.Они оба были гимназистами Царского Села,он несколько раз предлагал выйти за него замуж,получал отказ...наконец в 1910 она вышла за него замуж,в 1912 родился сын-Лев. Женитьба на Анне Горенко так и не стала победой для Николая Гумилева. Как выразилась одна из подруг Ахматовой того периода, у нее была своя собственная сложная «жизнь сердца», в которой мужу отводилось более чем скромное место. Да и для Гумилева оказалось совсем не просто совместить в сознании образ Прекрасной Дамы — объекта для поклонения — с образом жены и матери. У него были влюблённости, например чувство к Кузьминой-Караваевой. Ахматовой приходится несладко — она давно привыкла к тому, что является для Николая богиней, а потому ей тяжело быть свергнутой с пьедестала и осознавать, что муж способен испытывать такие же высокие чувства к другой женщине. Здоровье Машеньки быстро ухудшалось, и вскоре она  умерла. Правда, ее смерть не вернула Ахматовой былого обожания мужа. И тогда Анна Андреевна решается на отчаянный шаг и рожает Гумилеву сына Льва. Рождение ребенка Гумилев воспринял неоднозначно. Он тут же устраивает «демонстрацию независимости» и продолжает крутить романы на стороне. Впоследствии Ахматова скажет: «Николай Степанович всегда был холост. Я не представляю себе его женатым».

Впрочем, Ахматова тоже ведет себя отнюдь не так, как положено верной жене. В 1914 году Гумилев уезжает на фронт, и у Ахматовой завязывается бурный роман с поэтом Борисом Анрепом. И только эмиграция Анрепа в Англию поставила точку в их отношениях. Впрочем, Анреп был вовсе не единственным приближенным Ахматовой. Когда Гумилев наконец вернулся в Россию (после войны он провел некоторое время в Лондоне и Париже), в апреле 1918-го Ахматова сообщает ему: она любит другого, а потому им придется расстаться навсегда. Несмотря на прохладные отношения между супругами, развод стал для Гумилева настоящим ударом — оказывается, он все еще любил свою Прекрасную Даму Аню Горенко. Однако Ахматова непреклонна. Она переезжает к известному специалисту по Древнему Египту Владимиру Шилейко — именно он сумел покорить сердце великой поэтессы, пока ее муж мотался по фронтам, завоевывая награды (за проявленную храбрость Гумилев был награжден двумя Георгиевскими крестами). Сына Льва Ахматова оставляет жить у свекрови — поэтесса плохо представляла себя в роли заботливой матери.Это была какая-то странная жертва - ухаживать за больным.

Так что он вполне имел право сказать, что А.Ахматова его измучила, их брак был обречён в самом начале. А "мечты" о смерти - признак романтизма в творчестве всех символистов, есть и у Ахматовой, есть и у Гумилёва, автобиографичного здесь искать не стоит.

Comment: Людмила, в первую поездку в Египет (1909 г.), а, видимо, о ней идет речь, Гимилев-то и женат-то ещё не был. Он, конечно, мог быть измучен, но не Ахматовой, разве что своей нерешительностью, сделать наконец предложение.

Comment: Вы по ссылочке-то пройдите. Женат не был, а предложение 5 раз делал, она согласилась на 6-й,и,видимо, зря, изменила сразу же.

Answer (score 1):

А что там может иметь отношение к реальной жизни? Фраза "Я женщиною был тогда измучен"? Ну это наверняка знает только автор.

Написано на фоне неудачной второй женитьбы Гумилева на Анне Энгельгард. Но это - на момент написания стихотворения. А что там десять лет до того в Каире было...

http://www.e-reading.club/chapter.php/141885/330/Gumilev_-_Gde_nebom_konchilas%27_zemlya._Biografiya._Stihi._Vospominaniya.html

Остальное - просто эмоциональное описание увиденного в Каире.  Там нет фактов, которые можно сопоставить с реальной жизнью.

Comment: Т.е. в произведении автор объединил свои давние впечатления от посещения каирского сада и эмоции, возникшие гораздо позже в несчастливом браке. Мне это и требовалось.

Comment: Это я не буду гадать. Не литературовед и не критик, хотя Гумилева люблю. Я только по Фактам. Написано в 1919 г. после второй, не слишком удачной (как оказалось впоследствии) женитьбы. В начале века Гумиилев дважды (в 1909 и 1913 г., кажется) посещал Африку. Что у него там было с женщинами - история умалчивает.